# Get rid of the annoying message of emacs asking to add newline

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I am using org-mode to generate my PDF report. Each time the tex is generated, emacs asks me

> Buffer hw1.tex<2> does not end in newline.  Add one? (y or n) y

How can I get rid of this message and just add a new line automatically?

I tried setting mode-require-final-newline and require-final-newline to t, But this didn't change anything.

EDIT:
I also tried setting mode-require-final-newline and require-final-newline to nil, and even though I can check that their value changed (via C-h v), the problem still persists.

Following the advice of the comments, I added a hook to change the value of those variables:

> (add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
>                                (setq require-final-newline nil)
>                                (setq mode-require-final-newline nil)))

But again the problem  persists.

EDIT:

Also, I think I found the command responsible for this:

```
(el-get 'sync my-packages)
```

, so I suspect some package I installed is missing with my configuration.

Here is the list of the packages I installed using el-get:

```
           auctex
           auto-complete
           autopair
           color-theme-solarized
           cdlatex-mode
           ecb
           ein
           elpy
           expand-region
           flycheck
           folding
           gnuplot-mode
           helm
           helm-descbinds
           jedi
           js2-mode
           jump-char
           key-chord
           latex-preview-pane
           lua-mode
           magit
           markdown-mode
           matlab-mode
           multiple-cursors
           ;nxhtml
           nyan-mode
           org-mode
           outshine
           popup
           popwin
           pyenv
           pydoc-info
           scss-mode
           yaml-mode
           yasnippet
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is the opposite -- i.e., `(setq require-final-newline nil)` -- should eliminate the prompt.  To see what is happening and why, type `M-x find-function RET basic-save-buffer RET`  See also `M-x describe-variable RET require-final-newline RET`  How did I find this?  I grepped the Emacs source-code for "does not end in newline".  If a particular mode sets the value of `require-final-newline`, then you will likely need to reset the value to `nil` with a major-mode hook -- it happens so quickly, you won't notice the resetting.

Comment: @lawlist Please turn your comment into a proper answer so it can be accepted as correct.

Comment: @lawlist Can you please expand on why some modes reset the value of require-final-newline on the fly?

Comment: I edited my response to include more details about some of the things I tried.

Comment: To narrow down the culprit that may be in one of the packages you are using, type in an `org-mode` buffer:  `M-x describe-mode`  That will give you a list of minor-modes that are active.  Disable those minor modes in your configuration and restart Emacs.  See if that fixes your problem.  If it does, then load the minor modes one at a time and test after each one is enabled to see which one is responsible.  If the problem exists without any minor modes enabled, then you know they are not responsible -- so look elsewhere in your user-configuration.

Comment: I've just remebered I updated emacs recently, so now I deleted the old el-get folder and I am installing everything again. If that doesn't work, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: @lawlist, I discovered something: when I run `(setq require-final-newline nil)` using M-x from my .org buffer, the global value of `require-final-newline` doesn't change, but when I set from an other buffer, the global value change, and then org-mode doesn't ask for confirmation anymore. Is this behaviour expected?

Comment: `(set (make-local-variable 'require-final-newline) mode-require-final-newline)` derived by `org-mode` from `outline-mode` from `text-mode` (see answer below) takes a global variable `require-final-newline` and makes it buffer-local in `org-mode`.  So when you set it in `org-mode`, your only setting it buffer-locally.  Although beyond the scope of your question (yet related), you may someday be interested in using `setq-default` and `setq-local` to control the global and buffer-local values of a particular variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The following solution was tested with no user configuration -- i.e., **Emacs -Q** -- using Emacs 24.5.1.  Try loading Emacs with no user configuration and then add the solution and test.  Then try it with a full user configuration -- if it doesn't work with a full user configuration, it may be necessary to bisect and comment out code until the culprit is found.  It would probably be easier to just word-search the user-configuration for `require-final-newline`.]

As of the last stable public release of Emacs bearing version number 24.5.1, the default value of `require-final-newline` is `nil`.  The doc-string of that variable states (in part) that "*Certain major modes set this locally to the value obtained from `mode-require-final-newline`.*"  The function `basic-save-buffer` in the library `files.el` checks the value of `require-final-newline` (among other criteria) when making a decision to prompt the user with `(and require-final-newline (y-or-n-p (format "Buffer %s does not end in newline.  Add one? " (buffer-name))))`.  When enabling `org-mode` with no user configuration -- e.g., **Emacs -Q** -- the value of `require-final-newline` is set *locally* in the buffer as `t`.  The PARENT mode of `org-mode` is `outline-mode`; and the PARENT mode of `outline-mode` is `text-mode`.  `text-mode` when enabled contains a line of code that looks like this:  `(set (make-local-variable 'require-final-newline) mode-require-final-newline)`.  The variable `mode-require-final-newline` is defined in the library `files.el`, and the default value is `t`.

Now that we have done our due diligence, we can approach the problem from a couple of different angles.  We could change the global value of `mode-require-final-newline` by changing it from `t` to `nil`:  `(setq mode-require-final-newline nil)`.  Or, we could keep the new user-configuration buffer-local relating to `org-mode`:

```lisp
(defun my-org-mode-config-fn ()
  (setq require-final-newline nil))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-config-fn)
```

Comment: you are right, starting emacs with the -Q option makes everything work perfectly, so something must be wrong with my config file. But the weird part is this: if I start emacs with the "-Q" and then eval the buffer ".emacs", then again everything works. So now I am wondering, what does emacs do when started normally vs when starting with the -Q option (other than evaluating the .emacs file) ?

Comment: It could be something simple that a word search of `require-final-newline` will lead you straight to the culprit, or it could be something more complex that will take a bit more time to find.  When all else fails, use `M-x comment-region` on various sections of your `.emacs` file -- save and restart -- eventually you'll narrow it down.  Use `M-x uncomment-region` to remove the comments.